# php - is there some built-in way to get the last matched pattern?

Tags: php, regex, language-features

```
echo preg_replace("/f(o)o/", 'b$1r', 'This is foo.');

$var = ???   // here I want to get what $1 captured
```

For "built-in" I mean some PHP special variable, like [Ruby's `$1`](http://www.zenspider.com/Languages/Ruby/QuickRef.html#19).

If PHP hasn't a proper way to get that, what is the best way to achieve it?

Comment: @mofolo That way I'll have to perform the regex search twice: one for `preg_match` and another for `preg_replace`. When string is long or pattern is complex, that will be bad for performance.

Comment: I don't think it can be done in `preg_replace()`.   Maybe `preg_replace_callback()` and store the match in the callback function?

Comment: That's a possibility, if PHP really hasn't a built-in way to get `$1`.

Comment: what's your usecase ? there must be a better way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Comment: It isn't what I was looking for, but is the best way to achieve that. Thank's!